# Why is my MvcHtmlString's content being escaped?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've written a HtmlHelper extension method which reads content of CSS file and wraps it into a `<style>` tag:

```
public static IHtmlString EmbedCss(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string cssFile)
{
    var httpContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
    var physicalCssFileName = httpContext.Server.MapPath(cssFile);

    if (!File.Exists(physicalCssFileName))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
          string.Format("Requested CSS file \"{0}\" is not found",
                        physicalCssFileName));
    }

    var css = File.ReadAllText(physicalCssFileName);
    var tb = new TagBuilder("style");
    tb.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    tb.SetInnerText(css.TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' '));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tb.ToString());
}
```

Then I call this method in a view:

```
@Html.EmbedCss("~/assets/css/critical.css")
```

The quote and double-quoted characters from the CSS file are being encoded as `&#39;` and `&quot;` respectively.

If I replace the call of the extension method with the following code the quotation characters in the output aren't being encoded:

```
<style>
    @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(("~/assets/css/critical.css"))))
</style>
```

Could anybody explain why my extension method escapes the output?

Comment: MvcHtmlString encodes it for you, while Html.Raw does not

Comment: @AlexK [no, it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888864/mvc-html-extension-return-string-instead-of-html-markup).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
HtmlHelper.Raw does the following:

<!-- language: c# -->
    public IHtmlString Raw(string value) { 
        return new HtmlString(value);
    }

So I've changed the last line of my extension method as follows:

<!-- language: c# -->
    return new HtmlString(tb.ToString());

But it didn't change anything. The output is still being encoded.

Comment: @CodeCaster check the difference in return values between [MvcHtmlString.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.create(v=vs.118).aspx) and [HtmlHelper.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlexK [well, no](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/MvcHtmlString.cs). That documentation is incomplete. See [MvcHtmlString Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx) and [HtmlString Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring(v=vs.118).aspx): _"Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again"_. The `(Mvc)HtmlString` classes do not encode their input, and MVC doesn't encode their value when printing. Edit: did you _just_ change your name? :P

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`TagBuilder.SetInnerText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.setinnertext%28v=vs.111%29.aspx), which html-encodes the input:

> Sets the InnerHtml property of the element to **an HTML-encoded version of the specified string**.

Just assign the string to [`TagBuilder.InnerHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.innerhtml%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) directly to set the text as-is:

> Gets or sets the inner HTML value for the element.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> To HTML-encode a string before setting the InnerHtml property to the string, use the SetInnerText(String) method.